# NavigationMixin unavailable in lightning_FlowScreen

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a lwc set up to take in a record Id, and navigate to the record I'm attempting to use in a flow screen. The controller code is below. The problem is the navigation mixin still seems to be undefined in the flow screen context.

The original problem is that I have a flow that gets launched into a lightning tab, so using window.open/close does not work - and trying to use an aura wrapper to fire fore:navigateToURL or SObject from a Flow Action fails as well. I've also attempted to use an Aura wrapper implementing lightning:availableForFlowScreens and the worspaceAPI open/close tab but it doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas on how to control or redirect a lightning tab from a flow like this?

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class RedirectInCurrentTab extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){ 
    @api recordId;
    @api  leads = [];
    //Navigate to new lead
    navigateToViewLeadPage(){
        console.log(this);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Lead',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.navigateToViewLeadPage();
    }
}
```